# Spring Data JPA user posts

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have user login and profile view, I would like the users to have posts. Can someone guide me in the right direction?

I have a user entity:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "usr", indexes = { @Index(columnList = "email", unique = true) })
// using usr because in may conflict with the name of the class
public class User {

    public static final int EMAIL_MAX = 250;
    public static final int NAME_MAX = 50;

    /*
     * public static enum Role {
     * 
     * UNVERIFIED, BLOCKED, ADMINISTRATOR
     * 
     * }
     */

    // primary key long, needs to be annotated with @Id
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    // add columns
    @Column(nullable = false, length = EMAIL_MAX)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = NAME_MAX)
    private String name;

    // no length, the password will be encrypted to some longer value than the
    // user enters
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    /*
     * //email verification code
     * 
     * @Column(length = 16) private String verificationCode;
     * 
     * public String getVerificationCode() { return verificationCode; }
     * 
     * public void setVerificationCode(String verificationCode) {
     * this.verificationCode = verificationCode; }
     * 
     * 
     * @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) private Set<Role> roles = new
     * HashSet<Role>();
     * 
     * 
     * 
     * public Set<Role> getRoles() { return roles; }
     * 
     * public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) { this.roles = roles; }
     */

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean isEditable() {
        User loggedIn = MyTools.getSessionUser();

        if (loggedIn == null) {
            return false;
        }

        return loggedIn.getId() == id;
    }

}
```

and repo:

```
    public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    // @Query("select u from User u where u.email = ?1")
    User findByEmail(String email);

}
```

now, in order to have posts by that user, do I create a posts entity and repository with @manytoone in post pojo? 
I'm trying to make a twitter eventually but first I gotta get users to post. If you know of a good tutorial explaining this then that'd be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a second entity (java class) e.g. UserPost:

```
@Entity
@Table(...)
public class UserPost {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private long userId;

    ...
}
```

Then add @OneToMany relationship field to User. Cascading, lazy-loading, etc. depends on how you'd use it. It'd look like this inside User:

```
@OneToMany(cascade={...})
@JoinColumn(name="userId")
private Set<UserPost> posts;
```